# Where does this quote come from?

Tags: colonization, africa, quotes, victorian, ethiopia

Emperor Menelik II's [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelik_II#Notable_quotes) quotes him as saying "There was never a time when united that the Ethiopians lost to an enemy in history".

I am unable to find anywhere on the internet where this may have come from.
However, all the other quotes appear to be genuine and can be backed up by legitimate sources online.

Is this quote genuine? Is there a source not available on the internet that verifies this?

Comment: What language you've usually seen it in would probably be very helpful as well.

Comment: *There was never a time when united that Ethiopians lost to an enemy; it is non-existent in history*. (Emperor Menilek II, 1909).

Comment: @T.E.D I haven't seen the quote in any other language but english.

Comment: Thank you @Lucian, do you have a source for that quote?

Comment: @Giraffeshavelongnecks: [Best I could find](http://qavyjypatyj.dynalux-id.com/adwa-victory-centenary-conference-26-february-2-march-1996-book-7927ib.php). (Link won't open on direct click, for some reason).

Comment: @Lucian Thanks for that, hopefully there's an older source than that.